# selectOneButton cant submit while inside splitButton

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm using JSF 2 along with primefaces 5.1, i have a selectOneButton which have 2 values,
EN/FR, i want to be notified each time the language is changed, and then change the locale of the page.
Now the problem is that this selectOneButton is inside a splitButton, and for some reason, 
the ajax submit of the "change" event is always returning null for the selectOneButton, and it never passes the values selected.

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="headerForm">
    <p:splitButton>
        <p:menuitem>
        <p:selectOneButton id="langs" value="#{bean.lang}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="English" itemValue="en"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Françcais" itemValue="fr"/>
            <f:ajax event="change"/>
        </p:selectOneButton>
        </p:menuitem>
    </p:splitButton>
```

this just for testing:

```
public void setLang(String lang) {
        System.out.println("Changed: " + lang);
        this.lang = lang;
}
```

when i put the selectOneButton inside a p:menu for examples it works just fine.

Comment: Change `<f:ajax>` to `<p:ajax>` like this way : `<p:ajax process="@this" partialSubmit="true" listener="#{bean.action}"/>` (`process="@this"` can safely be omitted, since it already defaults to `@this`, by the way. Remove `listener="#{bean.action}"`, if not needed at all as you did not also mention in your example).

Comment: @Tiny Thank you so much, please post your answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is two-fold.

First, most PrimeFaces components, particularly the ones which generate hidden HTML input elements and are presented to enduser by a bunch of divs/lists with click listeners instead of as "plain HTML" inputs, require a `<p:ajax>` instead of `<f:ajax>` to be properly processed during ajax submits.

```
<p:selectOneButton id="lang" value="#{bean.lang}" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="English" itemValue="en"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Français" itemValue="fr"/>
    <p:ajax />
</p:selectOneButton>
```

Note that I omitted the `event` attribute as it has the right default value already, which would be `valueChange` in case of inputs and `action` in case of commands. The value of `change` is not necessarily the right default as some components would require `click` instead, particularly radiobuttons and checkboxes which have a fixed value.

In any case, the general recommendation is, if you're using PrimeFaces, just stick to `<p:ajax>` all the time. It'll use PrimeFaces-specific jQuery based Ajax API to process the ajax request instead of JSF native Ajax API and it's capable of dealing with PrimeFaces components.

Second, the JavaScript code associated with `<p:splitButton>` moves the HTML representation of the menu to end of body (in order to ensure best cross browser compatibility as to z-index). This however causes the menu to not be sitting in a form anymore. You can confirm it by looking at the HTML DOM tree in the webbrowser via rightclick and *Inspect Element* (not *View Source*!). You can solve this in basically 2 ways:

1. Move the form to inside the menu item. It wouldn't make sense anyway to submit all other menu items for this specific requirement.

   ```
   <p:splitButton>
       <p:menuitem>
           <h:form id="languageForm">
               <p:selectOneButton id="lang" value="#{bean.lang}" >
                   <f:selectItem itemLabel="English" itemValue="en"/>
                   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Français" itemValue="fr"/>
                   <p:ajax />
               </p:selectOneButton>
           </h:form>
       </p:menuitem>
   </p:splitButton>
   ```
2. Use `<p:ajax partialSubmit="true">` to let PrimeFaces Ajax API to collect the invidivual input values instead of searching for a `<form>` and [serializing](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) it (which would fail because there's no form).

   ```
   <h:form id="headerForm">
       <p:splitButton>
           <p:menuitem>
               <p:selectOneButton id="lang" value="#{bean.lang}" >
                   <f:selectItem itemLabel="English" itemValue="en"/>
                   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Français" itemValue="fr"/>
                   <p:ajax partialSubmit="true" />
               </p:selectOneButton>
           </p:menuitem>
       </p:splitButton>
   </h:form>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but for some reason, if you put the selectOneButton, you have to add "partialSubmit="true"" in the p:ajax, in order for it to work, if not, the "lang" property is always null